# MATLAB: I cannot input anything after "No completion found" message

Tags: matlab, windows-7

If there is no match for auto completion, I get "No Completions Found" message.

The problem is, when I got this message, I cannot input anything after that. To get able to input something, I have to move to different window and come back (e.g. Command Window -> Editor -> Command Window) or click the window. But this process is really annoying.

How can I continue typing without doing these annoying things written above? I am using MATLAB2011b on Windows 7.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I never faced such an issue. I usually press Escape to close the suggestions.

Comment: Even if I close suggestions with Escape key, I face the problem. In addition, now I found this problem happens to me for all cases relevant to auto complete. Even if I select one of the suggestions (e.g. type "inter" -> select "interp2"), then MATLAB does not allow me to type. I don't know where the problem comes from (MATLAB itself, OS, keyboard driver, ...).

Comment: I suggest you open a ticket with Mathworks support.